# Fancyhdr with modular document: documentclass book

Tags: header

I have seen this:

[Formatting headers in the book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170702/formatting-headers-in-the-book-class)

And I want what the asker has in their question:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}

\cfoot{} % get rid of the page number 

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I am able to run this MWE. However, I have a modular document: I input other .tex files and compile everything together into one document.

For example, I have (thesis.tex):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,twoside,final]{book}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{mathtools,dcolumn,epsfig,rotating,bm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %just added
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt} % width of margin notes
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt} % width of space between body text and margin notes
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.125in} % Adds 1/8 in. to binding side of all 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.125in} % Adds 1/8 in. to the left of all pages
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.375in} % assuming US letter paper (8.5 in. x 11 in.) and 
% side margins as above
\raggedbottom

%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
%\cfoot{} 
%\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\input{document1.tex}
\input{document2.tex}
\end{document}
```

For ease of replication, suppose document1.tex is:

```
% !TeX root = thesis.tex
\chapter{}
Text is here in chapter 1.
```

and document2.tex is:

```
% !TeX root = thesis.tex
\chapter{}
Text is here in chapter 2.
```

But I can't get the header to be *inside* the margin. That is, I want "CHAPTER 1" and all other headers to be within the upper margin area, instead of inside the text area.

EDIT: Maybe it's easier to ask: how do I put the header higher up on the page?

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're after. You mention that "the header [should] be *inside* the margin." Which margin?

Comment: Thanks @Werner, I mean that I would like the header to be inside the top margin. That is, I want it to be above the first line of text.

Comment: @Werner, that is, I'd like to have the header higher up on the page, and bring the bottom of the line that indicates where the header is, up to that point.

Comment: Do you really mean header? Or do you mean "chapter head"? When I compile the file you included, on pages 1 and 3 there are no headers, because for the first pages of new chapters a different pagestyle is usually used. On page 2 I see correctly the header "CHAPTER 1" appearing on the top right of the page (near the spine).

Comment: If you are asking about how to move the words "CHAPTER 1" that appears on page 1 higher up the page, what you are looking for is a way to customize chapter titles, and you should look into the [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) package.